# Jquery Ajax is not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using google form with my HTML and AJAX but the problem is it's working fine with chrome and i've also tested it in my mobile browser, it's working in Mobile Chrome but also not working in iphone's safari browser and it's not working with Firefox The code is following:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <h1 class="text-uppercase h3 f-open-sans-b text-center tgreen tmargin0">Order Form</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="entry.940219732" id="pName" hidden="true" value="Watch for Men" />
        <input type="text" name="entry.1912140262" id="pPrice" hidden="true" value="999" />
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" requitred="requitred"  value="" id="fname" name="entry.193588199" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" type="email"  value="" id="email" name="entry.1819118509" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control onlyNumerics" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number - 03451234567" requitred="requitred" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*"  value="" name="entry.1331713511" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Address" requitred="" id="address" name="entry.1955183047"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="city" rows="1" placeholder="City" name="entry.1929451429"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-12 bmargin10'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--<label class="control-label">Qty</label>    -->     
                <select id="size" name="entry.774706026" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="0">--Select Size--</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='col-md-12 bmargin10'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--<label class="control-label">Qty</label>    -->     
                <select id="color" name="entry.1992561494" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="0">--Choose Color--</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="qflag" class="col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 lpadding">
        <a class="btn btn-orange btn-block" id="x">
            <img src="https://www.example.com/images/quickbuy-icon.png" class="quickbuy-icon">
            Place Order
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tcenter">
        <img src="https://www.example.com/images/custom-loader.gif" class="balls_loader" alt="Loading...">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green" id="qload_btn" ><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>  


</form>
```

JavaScript Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#x").click(function () {
            var pName = $("#pName").val();
            var pPrice = $("#pPrice").val();
            var fname = $("#fname").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
            var address = $("#address").val();
            var city = $("#city").val();
            var size = $("#size").val();
            var color = $("#color").val();
            var status = "New Order";
            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            var dataString = 'entry.940219732=' + pName + '&entry.1912140262=' + pPrice + '&entry.193588199=' + fname + '&entry.1819118509=' + email + '&entry.1331713511=' + mobile + '&entry.1955183047=' + address + '&entry.1929451429=' + city + '&entry.774706026=' + size + '&entry.1992561494=' + color;
            if (fname == '' || email == '' || city == '' || address == '' || mobile == '')
            {
                alert("Please Fill All Fields");
            } else
            {

                // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfdjU4QZGY2NNdhYyw6qabSe9wSoryvpq563H_hQzjxDCqDRQ/formResponse",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
                window.location.replace("http://shoppyshopping.com/thanks.php");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

kindly help me, i'll be thanks full to you :)

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are you getting errors? Are you debugging? Have you checked the request info in dev tools? This is too vague.

Comment: page is redirecting but ajax request is not sending in firefox

Comment: http://shoppyshopping.com/productdetail.php?id=31

you can check the order form here

Comment: Have you checked the request in dev tools?

Comment: yup i've checked in dev tools, but request is not sending